# Creating duplicate line set distance away from a polyline in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance, polyline-creation

I'm new to QGIS and not really sure what I'm doing; I have a polyline of the UK coastline and I want to add another line 30 km offshore.

Is this possible?

Comment: The trace tool in QGIS 3 will support offset.

Comment: There is also the [Line Offset](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ParallelOffset/) plugin :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely possible. I presume, UK coastline is a closed linestring, or consists of n closed linestrings or multilinestrings as well. If so I recommend to convert it to polygons (or to one multipolygon, if preferred) using **Polygonize tool from the processing toolbox**, and then apply a 30 km buffer to the resulting (multi)polygon(s) (**processing toolbox: fixed distance buffer**).

Hint: If the coastline does not consist of closed linestrings, you should first edit your coastline in order to make sure, that it does.

The processing toolbox can be accessed under menu **Processing > Toolbox**, or **Ctrl-Alt-T**.

Answer (score 4):

In the processing toolbox you can use `v.parallel` in the GRASS commands

Answer (score 4):

Another tool for the same purpose than v.parallel is in

Processing toolbox - GDAL/OGR - OGR Geoprocessing - Single sided buffers (and offset lines) for lines.